# Can I model the Sun-illuminated planet system?

Tags: light

I am not related with 3d business at all. I just wanted to model a Moon terminator paradox. It is when Sun is below the horizon on the right and the Moon is above the horizon on the right and you see that it is illuminated from upper right corner, despite you would expect the the moon must be illuminated from lower right corner, where is the Sun. Can I model this with Blender? I am pig-ignorant about the 3D tools. I see that Blender tutorials say about point light source but can you locate it arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes it is doable with blender,and Yes you can set the light's location where you need it.

Comment: You can locate lamps wherever you want them, you can even use a *Sun* type lamp. If it's a real world physical phenomenon all you have to do is recreate a 3D scene with the correct relative position between the elements (moon, planet and sun)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos As I understand, Sun is a point source, which is easier to configure (no need to specify the direction of light) and indistinguishable from the Blender's Sun, which is nothing like a ball of light, which a true Sun is. I have realized that lighting sources are invisible themselves in the Blender. Yet, visible light sources are also possible by configuring the object material.

Comment: In this particular case you may have some difficulties dealing with distances because you would be dealing with very large (solar sistem-like) dimensions, I imagine. In this case blender's sun lamp provides some nice abstraction by creating itself parallel rays which is similar to what we almost end up receiving due to distance from the light source. As for the light source visibility you may create "fake objects"  to faithfully build whatever appearance you like.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have realized that distance and size is not necessarily gonna be huge. We can create a microscopic model. The light reaching the Earth-Moon is still going to be parallel, despite the Sun is very close, because microscopic Earth-Moon are going to be proportionally closer! I have learned myself how to create light-emitting materials to actually see the sun.